# Using JSON POST Request

Tags: javascript, json, api, post

I'm attempting to use JSON to initiate a POST request to an API.

I've found some example code, and before I get too far I wanted to get that working, but I'm stuck...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function JSONTest()
{
requestNumber = JSONRequest.post(
    "https://example.com/api/",
    {
        apikey: "23462",
        method: "example",
        ip: "208.74.35.5"
    },
    function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);
        }
    }
); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My JSON Web Page</h1>


<button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()">JSON</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a .html file, which I am running in chrome. Nothing happens when I click the button...

I think I'm missing a piece of javascript which interprets the JSON response and can be displayed? otherwise any other advice?

Comment: I was under the impression JSON was a subset of Javascript...? and so Javascript could run it with no problem?

Comment: JSON is a data-interchange format. Modern browsers can understand this, but older browsers need a library to be able to transform JSON strings, into JavaScript objects. I would recommend using a library such as jQuery to help you with this, as this will also solve some of the browser compatibility issues for older clients.

Comment: Most modern browsers have a JSON object available, but JSONRequest is not a natively available object or function on the window or document objects.

Comment: JSONRequest is only in a draft right now.

Comment: @kinakuta So are you saying I should import them? Or is there a solid JSON object already built in that you'd suggest?

Comment: If you want to use it, include a script making it available first: http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSONRequest-js.html

Comment: The Blogger API v3 allows client applications to view and update Blogger content. Your client application can use Blogger API v3 to create new blog posts, edit or delete existing posts, and query for posts that match particular criteria

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An example using jQuery is below. Hope this helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<title>My jQuery JSON Web Page</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

JSONTest = function() {

    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://example.com/api/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { apiKey: "23462", method: "example", ip: "208.74.35.5" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            switch (result) {
                case true:
                    processResponse(result);
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My jQuery JSON Web Page</h1>

<div id="resultDivContainer"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()">JSON</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Firebug debug process

[image: Firebug XHR debug process]

Comment: This is a great example! My problem is that its getting sent to the "request error" portion. I replaced everything with the nonexample data but it still won't work. I've contacted this API successfully and gotten a respnose back by using the PHP curl function and having the user enter apikey, method, and ip on an html page which posts to the php. Any other ideas how I could accomplish this and get a response using javascript?

Comment: Hi. I've updated my reply above, just changed the error handler, which should give you some more info on the error. Normally if that error handler is getting called its usually some sort of transport/cors error, as Jason mentioned. Try updating the code and seeing what the new error is. I would strongly recommend installing Fiddler, or using Google Chrome F12 Debug, so you can see 'exactly' what is happening 'under the bonnet'. Feel free to get back to me :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate you sticking with me on this. I've been working on getting this together for several days and can't even connect! Anyway, I tried the addition to the code. It gives just "0" back. I have firebug running, I'm new at using it, so if you have any requests on what piece you'd like me to examine I'll gladly do so!

Comment: Glad you getting your development environment setup. It's definately the way to go. If you press F12 so Firebug is running (I presume you are using FireFox), then select the [Net] tab, and then click XHR underneath. This will list all XHR (XMLHttpRequest) requests the browser makes. Don't worry, although you are working with JSON, the browser will list them under XHR regardless. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Uner URL: POST/api/ Status: Aborted Domain: example.com Size: 0 Remote IP: <address:port> It appears it gave up trying to contact it?

Comment: Domain: example.com? Double-check the web address and parameters are correct. Just for clarity, the apiKey, method, and particular ip parameter, are not used in connecting to the resource. That is purely set in the url field, e.g. url: "https://example.com/api/".

Comment: I cannot give out the real domain for confidentiality purposes, but otherwise it should be correct. The API is capable of more complex results with more information. APIkey, method, and ip are the bare minimum. The API will not run without a key, it must know which method is contacted and the ip it should be looking up. When you say these parameters are not used in connecting to the resource do you mean I should remove them? And then how would I submit this information so that the API can evaulate it?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. The 3 parameters are posted to the url, but they arent used to resolve the IP address for example. Just the domain will help the browser do that. The best way to debug your issue is to check Firebug. Using the [Net] -> [XHR] tabs it should be able to tell you exactly why this is failing, and even display the response from the remote server. I will upload a screen-shot into my post above to guide you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13815/discussion-between-phil-cartmell-and-user1475765)

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers do not currently implement JSONRequest (as far as I know) since it is only a draft right now.  I have found someone who has implemented it as a library that you can include in your page: http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSONRequest-js.html (please note that it has a few dependencies).

Otherwise, you might want to go with another JS library like jQuery or Mootools.