# how to send more than 255 byte string using query string in java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to send more than 255 byte string from one page to another page in JAVA,
(i.e var a="abcd......(8000 character)" now i want to pass this variable in to query string but it give error.

So how can i pass this data in to next page.

Please give some solution

I am Using json as follow:

```
xmlHTTP=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="path of jsp page?data=xyz"
xmlHTTP.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHTTP.send(null);
```

Here data=xyz and i want to send more than 80000 data replace of xyz using query string?

Answer (score 6):

Use a POST rather than a GET. The query string is limited in length, and you can't do anything about it. If you have a large amount of data to send, use a POST instead of a GET.

Comment: yes... but i am using javascript so get and post method is not possible

Comment: Of course it's possible. You can pass something other than null in send(). I advise you to use something like jQuery instead of the raw XMLHttpRequest, though. It will make the code more portable, and easier to write. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: it's possible to send more data using POST. but if i want to send Gujarati data in query String and then store that data on server database using encoding scheme. if i use post then i enable to encode and decode data on server side.here i want to send Gujarati data so i have to use GET. is there any option to send Gujarati data which is more than query-string range with post method?

Comment: I don't knwo what Gujarati data means. And i don't know why you could only send it using GET. If it's too long you don't have any other choice than using a POST. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML form type to "post"

If U'r using JSON, this may helpful for JSON POST request

[Using JSON POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456771/using-json-post-request)

Comment: :thanks for replay but i am using json so this is diffrent thing

Comment: You should edit your question and add this constraint to you'r question.

Comment: i dont want to call api i just want to one page using xmlHttpRequest Object.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can use request.setattribute() for setting and request.getattribute() For fetching it in destination

Comment: ya that i know but i want in javascript so how it is possible